# postgres function that should update date not executing

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have the following schema setup in PG 8.4   [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/27df2)

The idea is to write a generic function so that when ever the article relation is updated or the workshop relation is updated then the modified date is set to the current date.

I have this building fine but the functoion does not appear to actually update the date when ut should. This question looked interesting but it was not a generaly purpose function: [Accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494625/trigger-to-update-current-date-in-postgres-9)

What should I be doing to get thsi working?

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code in your question and don't link to an external site.

Comment: @Hyposaurus check my answer. Is it what you want or do you need more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used `AFTER` triggers for update value in NEW row. Try `BEFORE` triggers:

```
-- Articles table
CREATE TRIGGER update_articles_modified_date_to_now BEFORE UPDATE
ON articles FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
  update_modified_date_to_now();

-- Workshop table
CREATE TRIGGER update_workshop_modified_date_to_now BEFORE UPDATE
ON workshop FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
  update_modified_date_to_now();
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/23088/1)

Comment: Great this is the thing! Thanks for the help ((I went on holidays so that's the delay there.